# Dart: Asignar datos a variables con initState con Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo en una clase un parámetro de tipo `<Salamone>` que recibo de otra clase. Es el siguiente:

```
final Salamone value;
LineaDetalle({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);
```

La `Screen` contiene un `Slider`, que contiene una foto, descripcion y un año, a medida que se mueve el slider cambian los datos. (Vendria a ser como una linea de tiempo).

El problema que tengo que no me deja efectuar por defecto un valor para las variables. Las pongo vacias y una vez que muevo el slider tengo los datos.

Les dejo el link del codigo: https://github.com/emiibarra6/viviguamini/blob/master/lib/lineatiempo/ui/screen/LineaDetalle.dart

Donde las variables:

```
var anio = "";
  var sliderValue = 0.0;
  String foto = "";
  String Descripcion = "Desliza para ver mas info :)";
```

Quiero que esten por defecto:

```
var anio = "";
var sliderValue = widget.value.anio
String foto = widget.value.foto
String Descripcion = widget.value.descripcion;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu clase `_LineaDetalle` que extiende de `State` sobreescribe el método `initState` y asigna los valores:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
     sliderValue = widget.value.anio
     foto = widget.value.foto
     Descripcion = widget.value.descripcion;
     super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: +1, solo un detalle, la clase se llama `_LineaDetalle` y extiende `State` ;)